Nullspace etc using a different inner product over finite fields
In the context of coding theory, linear codes over finite fields make repeated use of kernels/nullspaces for creating e.g. parity check matrices.
However, often the "dot" product between two vectors is not the Dot of Mathematica but is something more involved like the Trace Hermitian Inner product:
$$ x \star y=\sum_i \textrm{tr }(x_i \bar{y_i}) $$
Is there any way to ask Mathematica to use a nonstandard notion of inner product (like $\star$) in its Linear Algebra routines?
The option to specify Nullspace[ ,Modulus-> 2] is already quite useful for codes over $\mathbb{F}_2$ but there does not seem to be enough flexibility for working with fields of the form $\mathbb{F}_{q=p^r}$

Check https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FiniteField.html?v=14.0 Examples > Scope > Linear Algebra over Finite Fields

@DanielLichtblau Yes I have seen that, as per In[13] in your link, there is a function NullSpace that is well-defined. However it uses the conventional (Euclidean) inner product between vectors over finite fields. I guess I was wondering whether there is some option to modify that behaviour. An example of the kind of thing I was hoping for would be the option SameTest which in the context of e.g.  Union gives you greater control over the notion of sameness. What I would like is greater control over the notion of Dot , and things downstream from that. Galois pkg for Python does it.

There is no Euclidean inner product in finite field vector spaces. I guess you mean it is based off n the “usual” dot product? Not sure if this can be used influenced in the way you want but maybe the ZeroTest option can be used?

Thanks for the tip with ZeroTest - that may turn out to be useful. There is a habit in coding theory literature (e.g. https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/s10623-016-0282-8.pdf Eq1.1) of labelling the conventional elementwise product as Euclidean inner product. It is perhaps not strictly correct.
